# .htaccess I think? Or php?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm making a user home system where users could visit each others home or view there own. This would work via `example.com/profile/username`

I have the .htaccess which currently is;

```
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)/?$ index.php?url=profile&user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Which basically enables the fact that I can now go and do `example.com/profile/Ryan` or any name at all! But the question is how can I make the html title tag say the person's username.
The engine I'm using enables me to `$_GET['user']` but when I do this I just get this:

[image]

I understand I'll probably have to echo it with some php so likewise I did...

```
<title>Wrex - <?php echo $_GET['user'] ?></title>
```

But this doesn't print anything and leaves the title as Wrex - :S

*PS: The file extension is `php`.*

Comment: Can you copy the title tag in here ?

Comment: This is probably you are using `.html` file instead of using `.php` file extension

Comment: <title>Wrex - <?php echo $_GET['user'] ?></title> also I'm using .php

Comment: Is php running? try `phpinfo();` in first line of profile.php.

Comment: @samitha No it's not about the extention because if it was. the result would be something like this `Wrex - <?php echo $_GET['user'] ?>`

Comment: Post more of your profile.php

Comment: Does anyone wanna help on a live viewer?

Comment: yes of course @user3067386

Comment: Okay here you goo :) https://secure.join.me/467-938-723 right i'm on

Comment: Create a file name 'info.php' with the only content `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` If you don't see something like [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nMnIa.jpg), you need to check your server configuration.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/2evlcz help on https://secure.join.me/467-938-723

Comment: try `index.php?url=X&user=Y`. put real values for `X` and `Y`.

Answer (score -1):

You can learn more about PHP and .htacces here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file

```
<?php
$username = (name)

if (!isset($username)) {
    // If the variable is not set (empty) set it to 'Guest'
    $username = 'Guest';
}

$title = sprintf('Welcome, %s!', $username);
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
</html>
```

[username as a page title (problem?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342756/username-as-a-page-title-problem)